# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for my code?

Tags: python, python-3.4

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "exceptionhandling.py", line 2, in <module>
     x = 5 + "ham" TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

My code:

```
try:
    x = 5 + "ham"

except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("won't see this")
finally:
    print("The final word")
```

I'm learning about exception handling. I know that there will be an error for the `5 + "ham"` and that I shouldn't see the `"won't see this"`, but why am I getting this error?

Comment: why are you trying to catch a `ZeroDivisionError`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP states:

> I'm learning about exception handling.I know that there'll be an error
>   for the 5 + ham and that i shouldnt see the "wont see this", but why
>   am I getting this error?

The code will raise an error unless you catch the correct error.  In the case, the correct error is `TypeError`:

```
try:
    x = 5 + "ham"

except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("won't see this")
except TypeError:
    print("Hey, these are the wrong types!")
finally:
    print("The final word")
```

The output from this code is:

```
Hey, these are the wrong types!
The final word
```

If you want to catch *every* error, then do:

```
try:
    x = 5 + "ham"

except:
    print("Something went wrong.")
finally:
    print("The final word")
```

Comment: why use `ZeroDivisionError` at all?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Good point.  I just added a quote from the OP's question to clarify that the OP's intent is to experiment with exception handling.

Comment: Thank you! You were the only person that realised why I was purposely creating the error, Thanks for providing a better example!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham The ZeroDivisionError was to try and show how it wont print the "wont see this" since its the wrong error.

Comment: @DamhanRichardson, if you knew how to catch an error why did you not catch the correct one, the traceback shows you exactly what type of error it is?